# Exlusive Options in Multi-Select Dropdown on Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I'm trying to make a Multi-Select drop down on mobile (Select Tag) trigger event after any option is clicked on. Both Click and Change events don't occur until after the user clicks "OK" in the popup window, I need to be able to run a check before and update the list with disabled options if said options are mutually exclusive. How would I do this?

Check this [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5wxmd7Lo/1/)

Using `$('option').click()`

Comment: Could you please provide the HTML and JS code so we can analyze why exactly the events aren’t working as intended?

Comment: Added the `.click()` method and  can add the `.change()` as well. Both work in desktop browser, but as soon as the select window pops up on mobile the check no longer happens until the user hits OK.

Comment: Moved the code sample link